# How to replace existing x-axis(numbers) with new x-axis(dates) in python, matplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code is fallowing:

```
import matploblib.pyplot as plt
dates_for_x = ['2020','2021','2022']
#Because of numerical process, I changed 'dates_for_x' to 'x'
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
plt.plot(x,y)
```

All elements in x correspond to specific dates as the given list, 'dates_for_x'.

How to replace x with dates_for_x when I plot?

Comment: Maybe you want `plt.xticks(x, dates_for_x)`?

Comment: Tahnk you so much!! it worked but I am very curious how I can show some of data in the dates_for_x on the x-axis. For example I wanna show only 2020 and 2022 on the x-axis. Thank u in advance. Have a nice day!! :)

Comment: Maybe `plt.xticks(x[::2], dates_for_x[::2])`?

Comment: Thank u so much, it works well! :) You are modest and have a gigantic mind. Have a great great and great day!!!! :)